# Access this variable in render method [REACT NATIVE]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing an issue trying to render a class variable.

```
import Api from '../services/Api';
class Boxify extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  async componentWillMount() {
    this.response = await Api.getUserCurrent();
    this.mail = this.response.data.email;
    alert(this.mail);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {this.mail}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default Boxify;
```

What I can't figure out is why does the alert in the componentWillMount shows me the email_adress, and the render doesn't show anything ?

Comment: Because when the component is first rendered, `this.mail` is undefined. And since you aren't calling `setState()` / using `this.state` like you're supposed to, `render()` isn't called again. Either make `mail` part of the component's state, or force a re-rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using state instead of a local variable, so the component will render again

```
import Api from '../services/Api';
class Boxify extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     mail : ''
   }
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.response = await Api.getUserCurrent();
    this.setState({
         mail : this.response.data.email;
     })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {this.state.mail}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default Boxify;
```

Comment: either change the state variable to `mail` or use `data` instead of `mail` in render and set state of componentDidMount

Comment: yeah, fixed my typo sorry.

Comment: Worked ! Thanks mates.